# Swift Initializer Mystery

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, initializer

Few blocks of code:

This works:

```
import Foundation

class Class1 {
    init(param1: String?) {
        print("hello")
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(param1: nil)
    }
}

class SubClass1: Class1 {

}

let obj = SubClass1()
```

In the above code, the designated initialiser is passed down to SubClass1 because SubClass1 does not provide its own designated initialiser. Also, convenience initialiser is also passed down. Therefore, this works.

```
import Foundation

class Class1 {
    init(param1: String?) {
        print("hello")
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(param1: nil)
    }
}

class SubClass1: Class1 {
    override init(param1: String?) {
        print("hello 2")
        super.init(param1: nil)
    }
}

let obj = SubClass1()
```

This works too because SubClass1 has provided its own designated initialiser now.

```
import Foundation

class Class1 {
    init(param1: String?) {
        print("hello")
    }

    init(param2: String?) {
        print("world")
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(param1: nil)
    }
}

class SubClass1: Class1 {
    override init(param1: String?) {
        print("hello 2")
        super.init(param1: nil)
    }
}

let obj = SubClass1()
```

This gives "error: missing argument for parameter 'param1' in call" for the last line.
Here, there is a designated initialiser for SubClass1 and convenience initialiser from parent also calls the same initialiser, then why the error?

This

```
import Foundation

class Class1 {
    init(param1: String?) {
        print("hello")
    }

    required init(param2: String?) {
        print("world")
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(param1: nil)
    }
}

class SubClass1: Class1 {
    override init(param1: String?) {
        print("hello 2")
        super.init(param1: nil)
    }

    required init(param2: String?) {
        print("world")
        super.init(param2: nil)
    }
}

let obj = SubClass1()
```

and this works:

```
import Foundation

class Class1 {
    init(param1: String?) {
        print("hello")
    }

    init(param2: String?) {
        print("world")
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(param1: nil)
    }
}

class SubClass1: Class1 {
    override init(param1: String?) {
        print("hello 2")
        super.init(param1: nil)
    }

    override init(param2: String?) {
        print("world")
        super.init(param2: nil)
    }
}

let obj = SubClass1()
```

Why does it need all the designated initialisers to be overridden for the one convenience initialiser to work that calls just one of the designated initialisers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is clearly stated in the [swift guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html).

> Assuming that you provide default values for any new properties you
>   introduce in a subclass, the following two rules apply:
>
> **Rule 1** If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it
>   automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> **Rule 2** If your subclass provides an implementation of ***all*** of its
>   superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per
>   rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its
>   definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass
>   convenience initializers.

So basically, your subclass must override/define all of the superclass' designated initialisers to get the superclass' convenience initialisers inherited.